# Kernel panic when I try to install Ubuntu on my PC

Tags: system-installation, kernel, 19.04

I made a USB with 19.04 following the guide and tried to start it for installation, but I got a kernel panic. I tried an older version and couldn't install it either, but a 14.04 LiveUSB worked OK when I made it earlier.  How do I solve the kernel panic problem with installation?

- Processor: [AMD Ryzen 3 2200G](https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-3-2200g)
- Motherboard: [ASRock A320M-HDV](https://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/A320M-HDV/index.asp)
- RAM: 16GiB Dual Channel
- Graphics Card: [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/151568)

Yes I did try LTS and also checked the USB - it is completely fine; I can install a VM with the USB but not on my computer.

Comment: Here are relevant troubleshooting steps: 1) This guide https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu or this  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows or some other guide? 2) Did you checksum-verify the downloaded ISO before making the LiveUSB? 3) Please download 18.04.3 https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop , verify w/ checksum, and make a LiveUSB, and test installation with the stabler LTS version. Please click [edit] and post the answers to 1, 2, and 3 in your question. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: Nvidia hardware will need the "nomodeset" edited onto the grub line starting with "linux" at the words "quiet splash" (editing instructions at bottom of grub menu page). Try adding acpi=no to see if the installation works, then refine the acpi switch to the minimum necessary (for problems like seeing only 1 cpu, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if you had taken out the computer battery and reset the cmos. Worked for me when I couldn't install today.

Comment: I haven't changed anything in my bios but when I can check this out i will tell you

Comment: Didn't work any other ideas

Comment: Maybe provide the previously requested info about your system?